# How to verify if user has default avatar on it's github profile? ( GraphQL API v4 )

Tags: graphql, github-api

Using [GraphQL API v4](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql),One can get the avatar url for specific user. Now I want to verify if the user has default avatar or not.

Query

```
{
    user(login: "username") {
        avatarUrl
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "avatarUrl": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/..."
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not able to find any solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to solve this using regex pattern.

Look into below code for better understanding.

```py
import re

avatar_url = "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/28740468?u=46fc1fffb60b3ede9928c4845f0e0f26034ea8e0&v=4"

patten = re.compile(r"(\?u=[a-z0-9]+&v=[0-9])")

d = patten.search(avatar_url) is None

print(d)
```

- Basically, GitHub avatar URL will have something like `u=46fc1fffb60b3ede9928c4245f0e0f26034ea8e0`, if the user has uploaded the profile picture.
- The user who has a default avatar will not have this string in their avatar URL structure.